# continuity at a point in a cadlag process

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, continuity

I am reading a proof that uses the fact:

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a cadlag process. We know that $X(\omega)$ has at most countably many discontinuities, for each $\omega \in \Omega$. It is then stated that

> For any fixed $t \geq 0$, then process $X$ is continuous at $t$ almost surely.

I don't see how having countably many discontinuities relates to the measure of sample paths that are continuous at $t$.

Comment: This holds for all but countable number of $t$, see Billingsley "Convergence of Probability Measures", section 13.